# Create an invisible rectangle between two rectangles

Tags: libgdx

Currently I have two rectangles one is located on the top and another is at the bottom, they have the identical width but different height, just like in the game FlappyBird. Between them there is a gap, I hope to make an invisible object between them. This object will trigger a get score method once the player flies through it successfully without colliding with the two rectangles. May I know how to create it? Thank you.

[image: I want to make an invisible box(shown in red) between these two black rectangles]

Comment: Why not just increase your score when player position X is more then some of your rectangles position X?

Comment: @icarumbas Silly me! Didnt think that before haha, tried your solution and it works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

only getColor and set opacity to 0

```
[actor].getColor().a = 0;
```

Comment: if set opacity to 0 object invisible. exist but not show in your game